# Программа для создания схемы формы

Tags: java, дизайн, c++, форма

Есть ли программное обеспечение, позволяющее создавать наброски экранных форм, чтобы  было проще себе представлять, что получится на выходе?
Конструкторы форм встроенные в `NetBeans` и `VS` не предлагать, мне нужно получить просто схематический рисунок.

Comment: В Microsoft Visio есть возможность создавать набросок формы, но не более. Его возможности достаточно скудные, но чтобы просто представить форму с пятью контролами сойдет.

Подходит?

p.s. Для ответа маловато..

Comment: Использование метки `c++` тут, наверное, излишне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помимо MS Visio, за который MS хочет немало денюжек есть другие варианты:

- Бесплатный [Pensil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx)
- Платный "убийца Visio" [SmartDraw](http://www.smartdraw.com/)
- [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)

Облачные сервисы с бесплатными и не очень аккаунтами (бесплатный план или trial у всех есть):

- [Cacoo](https://cacoo.com/)
- [Mockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/)

Comment: во!..пасибо)

Answer (score 0):

WireframeSketcherStudio